# Change all bit columns to int with default value NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database where we would store Yes/No questions as bits. However, as the project is going to a different path, we need to change all **bit** data types to **int** with default value **NULL**.

Trying the following query, I get object is dependent of column error.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Customers ALTER COLUMN **[Is item returned?]** int not null;
```

To fix this I try doing:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Customers DROP CONSTRAINT DF_Customers_[Is item returned?]
ALTER TABLE dbo.Customers ALTER COLUMN [Is item returned?] int not null
ALTER TABLE dbo.Customers WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Customers_[Is item returned?]] DEFAULT NULL FOR [Is item returned?]
```

However, the fact that the column is in [brackets] is making this throw syntax errors. Should this be fixed with quotes? What are your opinions?

Comment: Your bracketing seems to be completely broken.

Comment: If you avoid object names that require delimit identification, then this type of problem can be much more easily avoided.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, it is the first time I am working on a db where columns have delimiters like this, so I did mess up the bracketing. However, is the query correct? It does convert to int with default value (NULL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is I had to **add more brackets as delimiters** to fix the syntax. The following query works perfectly:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Customers DROP CONSTRAINT [DF_Customers_Is item returned?]
ALTER TABLE dbo.Customers ALTER COLUMN [Is item returned?] int not null
ALTER TABLE dbo.Customers WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Customers_Is item returned?] DEFAULT NULL FOR [Is item returned?]
```

Comment: And yet it still makes no logical sense. You defined the column as **not null**, so adding a default of null is utter nonsense. And switching from bit to int seems extreme. Why not tinyint? How many values does a flag-type column actually need? Maybe all you really need to do is cast your original bit column to more common numeric datatype. Seems much more like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). And at some point you need to enforce that constraint - so why NOCHECK?